# Remove the text and its background

Tags: android, android-studio

Based on the picture with the text "Dice"

how do you remove the text dice with the blue background color?

Im newbie in android and im using API 25

[image]

Thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:context="com.jfdimarzio.dice.ResultActivity">

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: I didn't understand why you put TableLayout xml in here if you find where and what element set "Dice" you can put "" (empty) on setText attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Create new style for NoActionBar activity in style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**Step 2:** Apply this in your Activity from Manifest.xml

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

**Step 3:** extends your activity from AppCompatActivity

```
public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change it from manifest file.

you have `android:label="@string/app_name"`

and `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`

change both you will get the result.